# background package causes tikz error when verbatim page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, verbatim, backgrounds, debugging

#### The `background` package causes a tikz error with `verbatim`

I have a few lines of of text within begin/end `verbatim`, and normally this would just break over a page where needed, however, when I use the `background` package, it produces some a `tikz Error`:
`Package tikz Error: Sorry, some package has redefined the meaning of the matht cause unrecoverable errors. \end{verbatim}`
I've since been able to live without the package, but I'm curious about **why is the error happening, is there a workaround, or is this a bug in the package?** This only happens when the verbatim breaks over a page, as in the MWE if I reduce the lipsum so it doesn't page break, then the error goes away.

#### MWE

To get the line break just right I've added some dummy sentences where needed.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{background} % Letting me add background overlays. 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4] % Change this to \lipsum[1-3] and it goes away.

Some very long sentences repeated over and over again. Some very long sentences repeated over and over again. Some very long sentences repeated over and over again. Some very long sentences repeated over and over again. Some very long sentences repeated over and over again. 

Some interesting code
\begin{verbatim}
foo 
bar
\end{verbatim}
does something.

\end{document}
```

Comment: well it puts (with everypage) lots of complicated code into the shipout without guards against unusual catcodes settings from verbatim or listings. So I would say it is a bug, but I don't see an easy place to inject code to reset the catcodes locally (and personally I prefer either eso-pic, or with the upcomming latex the new shipout hook).

Comment: looking at it more closely, I don't think anymore that it is a background problem. It is more a pgf problem: the error message is wrong here,

Comment: I opened an issue for pgf/tikz: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/927